# Binding GrivdViewColumn's Width Property in XAML or in Code?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I would like to bind GrivdViewColumn's Width Property with my ViewModel. Lets say an instance of ViewModel is the Datacontext of the Window. ViewModel has got Properties called IdWidth, LastNameWidth, FirstNameWidth. And that Window contains the following given ListVeiw in a stackPanel. Everything is fine but somehow the Width Property of GridViewColumn is not bound. Please post the code after making sure that it works.

```
<ListView Name="PatientListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Patients}"
          SelectionMode="Single">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridView.Columns>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Patient-Id"
                        Width="{Binding IdWidth, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PatientId}"/>

        <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name"
                        Width="{Binding LastNameWidth, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"/>

        <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name"
                        Width="{Binding FirstNameWidth, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
      </GridView.Columns>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: FrameworkElement is not **required** for DataBinding, sorry for this incorrect interpretation of the citation from MSDN below.
See comments and @H.B. 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8589428/314334)

<strike>[GridViewColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.aspx) does not inherit from [FrameworkElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms602714.aspx), which is required for databinding.</strike>

see MSDN:

> **Support for data binding and dynamic resource references**: [...], but the ability to resolve a member value that is stored as an Expression (the programming construct that underlies both data binding and dynamic resources) is implemented by FrameworkElement

Comment: Thanks Stephan. Oh I did't even think about that. U saved my time.

Comment: You're welcome. I just had exactly the same problem with `DataGridColumn` a few weeks ago ;)

Comment: This is incorrect. You only need to inherit from `DependencyObject` for data binding, you can try to bind the header, it works just fine, my guess is that the binding path or the DataContext is just off.

Comment: @H.B. : I am setting the DataContext of window explicitly in code with 
            DataContext = new StudyModelViewModel();
But its not working. And as I said VielModel contains all the properties.

Comment: When I change the value of the property in Viewmodel and raise OnPropertyChanged method, then PropertyChanged is always null. Which means there is no listener of this event. But if binding the wokring then u know its not null. Which should be the case.

Comment: @Saghar: What are the ***[binding errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)***?

Comment: @H.B. Here is the binding error.
System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error: 'ColumnsWidh' property not found on 'object' ''StudyModelViewModel' (HashCode=43148459)'. BindingExpression:Path=LastNameWidth; DataItem='StudyModelViewModel' (HashCode=43148459); target element is 'GridViewColumn' (HashCode=25209742); target property is 'Width' (type 'Double')

Comment: @Saghar: You do recognize the difference between a property and a field, right? And that the property needs to be public, no?

Comment: I edited my answer since it seems to turn out that my statement was just wrong, sorry for that. But now I wonder what my problem was with the `DataGridColumn`. I'll take a look a the Binding Error when I'm back at my PC and probably add a question here then.... Thanks @H.B. :-)

Comment: @StephanBauer: `DataGridColumns` are different, sadly i do not know the specifics. They do not have the expected `DataContext`, which often causes problems for people who try to bind the `ItemsSource` on the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.

Comment: @H.B. >> I know it very well and they are in deed public. But unfortunately its not working. Can u please try it ur self with a small sample program?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is wrong as outlined in my comment, looking at your paths you seem to expect the `DataContext` to be the item, which cannot work (there are multiple items to begin with, which should be chosen?).

The `DataContext` of the columns is the `DataContext` of the `ListView`.

This example will result in a column with the Header `Lorem Ipsum`:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.DataContext>
        <Label Content="Lorem Ipsum"/>
    </ListView.DataContext>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Content}"/>
            </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Also you might be interested in [this article on debugging databindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx).